# Change default paste options

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Since a few hours ago, when I paste with Ctrl+V in Excel 2010, it pastes values, not formulas. It appears that the default has changed, I do not know how.
From what I found, that can only be done assigning the shortcut to a suitable macro (I know I did not do that!).

Any hint on how to change it?

Comment: I used two possibly redundant keywords for this question (how to suggest removing one of them from the available options?)

Comment: @pnuts - (a) Restarting Excel did not help. Did not reboot though. (b) Ok, I will migrate. (c) Strange, I did not do anything related with add-ins.

Comment: @pnuts - I think it is convenient to keep some keyords in the title, for readability and "searchability". I was referring to tags< to eliminating one of them from the available options, not from those assigned to this specific question.

Comment: @pnuts - It appears that I can't request migration... rep<3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was copying a range which span hidden cells due to filtering. Then, pasting used "as values" by default. When the copied range did not span any filtered out cell, paste went back to normal.

Something new/unexpected every day (especially when it comes to MS)...